# Is there a floor function in Mongodb aggregation framework?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I try to do some integer math in mongodb and have some problems. Is there a way to round doubles up or down in the mongo db aggregation framework?

Comment: Looks like the best I can do is using modulus and subtract like so: (num-mod(num,1)).  It still spits out a double, but at least it is an integer-valued double. (and I can cast client side).

Comment: The [Aggregation Framework arithmetic functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) for MongoDB 2.2 do not include `$floor` or `$ceiling`.  If there are functions or operators you would like to see added, please suggest these in the [MongoDB SERVER project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER), with the component "Aggregation Framework".

Comment: Looking through the documentation myself, that's what I figured, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.  Luckily I have a work around for now. :)  (Aside: I will fill out a feature request at some point in the future).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the comment from Stennie, the floor and ceiling methods are not supported.

And as per my comment above, the best solution that I could find was just doing an operation that looks like: (num-mod(num,1)) which should yield the same result as the floor function.

Comment: This will soon be available: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_floor

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#new-aggregation-arithmetic-operators), you can use the following arithmetic aggregation operators are available:

- [`ceil`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/)
- [`trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/)
- [`floor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/)

which allow to convert to integer from any side you want. The syntax is straight-forward: `{ $function: <number> }`

Comment: I commented that on November 4th, on my original answer ;)

Comment: @CasualT and I just wrote that up with a little bit more details, once I read the new documentation :-)