# Can I group floating point numbers by range in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB set up with documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544ced7b9f40841ab8afec4e"),
    "Measurement" : {
        "Co2" : 38,
        "Humidity" : 90
    },
    "City" : "Antwerp",
    "Datum" : ISODate("2014-10-01T23:13:00.000Z"),
    "BikeId" : 26,
    "GPS" : {
        "Latitude" : 51.20711593206187,
        "Longitude" : 4.424424413969158
    }
}
```

Now I try to aggregate them by date and location and also add the average of the measurement to the result. So far my code looks like this:

```
db.stadsfietsen.aggregate([
    {$match: {"Measurement.Co2": {$gt: 0}}},       
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                hour: {$hour: "$Datum"},
                Location: {
                    Long: "$GPS.Longitude",
                    Lat: "$GPS.Latitude"
                }
            },
            Average: {$avg: "$Measurement.Co2"}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {"_id": 1}},
    {$out: "Co2"}
]);
```

which gives me a nice list of all the possible combinations of hour and GPS coordinates, in this form:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "hour" : 0,
        "Location" : {
            "Long" : 3.424424413969158,
            "Lat" : 51.20711593206187
        }
    },
    "Average" : 82
}
```

The problem is that there are so many unique coordinates, that it's not useful.

Can I group the documents together when there are values that are close together? Say from Longitude 51.207 to Longitude 51.209?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard support for ranges in `$group`.

**Mathematically**

You could calculate a new value that will be the same for several geolocations. For example you could [simulate a floor method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13960353/199048):

```
_id:{ hour:{$hour:"$Datum"}, Location:{
        Long: $GPS.Longitude - mod($GPS.Longitude, 0.01),
        Lat: $GPS.Latitude - mod($GPS.Latitude, 0.01)
}}
```

**Geospatial Indexing**

You could restructure you're application to use a [Geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) and search for all locations in a given range. If this is applicable depends very much on your use case.

**Map-Reduce**

[Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) is more powerful than the aggregation framework. You can definitely use this to do your calculations, but it's more complex and therefore I can't present you a ready-made solution without spending another hour.

Comment: Worked great! Geospatial indexing wasn't useful to me, as the results were to be used for heatmapping, so I needed all the results.