# Mongo aggregation within intervals of time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some log data stored in a mongo collection that includes basic information as a request_id and the time it was added to the collection, for example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ae6ea558a5d3fe018b4568"),
    "request_id" : "030ac9f1-aa13-41d1-9ced-2966b9a6g5c3",
    "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T16:00:00.00Z")
}
```

I was wondering if I could use the aggregation framework to aggregate some statistical data. I would like to get the counts of the objects created within each interval of N minutes for the last X hours.

So the output which I need for 10 minutes intervals for the last 1 hour should be something like the following:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:00:00.00Z"), "count" : 67 }
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:10:00.00Z"), "count" : 113 }
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:20:00.00Z"), "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:30:00.00Z"), "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:40:00.00Z"), "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 0, "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T15:50:00.00Z"), "count" : 34 }
```

I would use that to get data for graphs.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of ways of approaching this depending on which output format best suits your needs. The main note is that with the ["aggregation framework"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) itself, you cannot actually return something "cast" as a date, but you can get values that are easily reconstructed into a `Date` object when processing results in your API.

The first approach is to use the ["Date Aggregation Operators"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) available to the aggregation framework:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "time": { "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$time" },
            "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$time" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$time" },
            "minute": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$minute": "$time" },
                    { "$mod": [ { "$minute": "$time" }, 10 ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which returns a composite key for `_id` containing all the values you want for a "date". Alternately if just within an "hour" always then just use the "minute" part and work out the actual date based on the `startDate` of your range selection.

Or you can just use plain "Date math" to get the milliseconds since "epoch" which can again be fed to a date contructor directly.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "time": { "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
               { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date(0) ] },
               { "$mod": [
                   { "$subtract": [ "$time", new Date(0) ] },
                   1000 * 60 * 10
               ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

In all cases what you **do not** want to do is use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) before actually applying [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). As a "pipeline stage", `$project` must "cycle" though all documents selected and "transform" the content.

This takes **time**, and adds to the execution total of the query. You can simply just apply to the `$group` directly as has been shown.

Or if you are really "pure" about a `Date` object being returned without post processing, then you can always use ["mapReduce"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/), since the JavaScript functions actually allow recasting as a date, but slower than the aggregation framework and of course without a cursor response:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
   function() {
       var date = new Date(
           this.time.valueOf() 
           - ( this.time.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) )
       );
       emit(date,1);
   },
   function(key,values) {
       return Array.sum(values);
   },
   { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Your best bet is using aggregation though, as transforming the response is quite easy:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "time": { "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$time" },
            "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$time" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$time" },
            "minute": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$minute": "$time" },
                    { "$mod": [ { "$minute": "$time" }, 10 ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc._id = new Date(doc._id);
    printjson(doc);
})
```

And then you have your interval grouping output with real `Date` objects.

Comment: Great tip of using a group before the actual project, it is nice to know that projects are cycling through all the documents if used before group. One thing which I would like to achieve here (I have updated my question) is actually getting a count of 0 in the result for empty intervals (intervals that do not include any objects) as I am passing these to a graph framework. That would save time for parsing and adding that in the actual code where the data is used. Is that achievable?

Comment: @JeromeWalters Not a wise thing to do really. If you think about it, you can only really "sum" on keys that "exist". So while it is "possible" to throw in every "possible" key within the range, it really is not practical since you are throwing in a variable containing all of those key. The smart money is on "combining" that result with blank expected ranges in your API code, rather than "throwing" all those values at the server. Same applies to SQL variants of the same thing. Just because you "can" doesn't mean you "should".

Comment: @JeromeWalters Also "changing your question" so it is essentially "different" from what you asked. Not received very well here. If an answer leads you to another question, then "ask another question" instead.

Comment: Combining with blank expected ranges in the API sounds like the right thing thanks for pointing out. I would have in mind that changing the question is not a smart thing to do. It makes sense as it could lead to different answers as you suggested. Sorry about that, I am new here, still getting sense of the environment. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
pipeline = [
    {"$project":
        {"date": {
            "year": {"$year": "$time"},
            "month": {"$month": "$time"},
            "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$time"},
            "hour": {"$hour": "$time"},
            "minute": {"$subtract": [
                {"$minute": "$time"},
                {"$mod": [{"$minute": "$time"}, 10]}
            ]}
        }}
    },
    {"$group": {"_id": "$date", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
]
```

Example:

```
> db.foo.insert({"time": new Date(2015,  7, 21, 22, 21)})
> db.foo.insert({"time": new Date(2015,  7, 21, 22, 23)})
> db.foo.insert({"time": new Date(2015,  7, 21, 22, 45)})
> db.foo.insert({"time": new Date(2015,  7, 21, 22, 33)})
> db.foo.aggregate(pipeline)
```

and output:

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 8, "day" : 21, "hour" : 20, "minute" : 40 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 8, "day" : 21, "hour" : 20, "minute" : 20 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 8, "day" : 21, "hour" : 20, "minute" : 30 }, "count" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

a pointer in lieu of a concrete answer. you can very easily do it for minutes, hours and given periods using the [date aggregations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) . every 10 minutes will be a bit trickier but likely possible with some wrangling. nevertheless, the aggregation will be slow as nuts on large data sets.

i would suggest extracting the minutes post-insert

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ae6ea558a5d3fe018b4568"),
    "request_id" : "030ac9f1-aa13-41d1-9ced-2966b9a6g5c3",
    "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T16:00:00.00Z"),
    "minutes": 16
}
```

and even though it sounds utterly absurd adding quartiles and sextiles or whatever that N might be.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ae6ea558a5d3fe018b4568"),
    "request_id" : "030ac9f1-aa13-41d1-9ced-2966b9a6g5c3",
    "time" : ISODate("2015-07-21T16:00:00.00Z"),
    "minutes": 16,
    "quartile: 1,
    "sextile: 2,
}
```

first try doing a [$div](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) on the minutes. doesnt do ceil and floor. but check out

[Is there a floor function in Mongodb aggregation framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617526/mongodb-aggregation-framework-floor-function-does-it-exist)

Comment: The [`$mod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) operator does this easily.