# MongoDB using a C# driver and time interval LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

When using the C# MongoDB driver - is it possible using LINQ to create an aggregation that create a result that groups the results in time intervals - like this:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$project":
        {"date": {
            "year": {"$year": "$time"},
            "month": {"$month": "$time"},
            "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$time"},
            "hour": {"$hour": "$time"},
            "minute": {"$subtract": [
                {"$minute": "$time"},
                {"$mod": [{"$minute": "$time"}, 10]}
            ]}
        }}
    },
    {"$group": {"_id": "$date", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
]
```

From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550807/600559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some quick and dirty sample code in LINQPad

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
    var col = db.GetCollection<Foo>("foos");
    col.AsQueryable().Select(x => new Projection { Date = new Date { Year = x.Time.Year, Month = x.Time.Month, Day = x.Time.Day, Hour = x.Time.Hour } }).GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => new Result { Count = x.Count(), Id = x.Key });
}

public class Foo
{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}

public class Projection
{
    public Date Date {get;set;}
}

public class Date
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Hour {get;set;}
}

public class Result
{
    public Date Id {get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}
}
```

Basically what I've done is followed the docs on the C# driver [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/driver/crud/linq/).

I've written some strong typed classes just to illustrate some points. They are not needed as you can see from the example in the docs. Anonymous types are just fine. The `AsQueryable()` method just runs the LINQ Expression through a translator to the aggregation pipeline on the server. I didn't completely solve the problem for you, but I hope you get the gist.

Keep in mind that there are things expressible in LINQ that cannot be expressed in the aggregation framework so even if something compiles it doesn't guarantee it will run, so make sure to test ahead of time.

Comment: But this does not group the results into equal intervals? Does it? The GroupBy(x => x.Date) looks like it groups into dates?

Comment: If you look at the `Date` object, you will see it contains `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, and `Hour`, which means it will group data into hour long buckets. If you need more granular bucketing, you will need to modify the code to include more parts of the `DateTime`. That being said, this answer is intended to give you the tools to solve your particular problem, not solve it for you. After all, half the fun of coding is solving the problem.