# How to aggregate by floor in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

MongoDB Aggregation Framework doesn't have `floor` function.
It only has simple [arithmetic operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/).
So, how to compose `floor` function using them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a floor function in Mongodb aggregation framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617526/is-there-a-floor-function-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to definition `floor(number) = number - (number % step)` we can compose our aggregation formula:

```
{$subtract: ["$number", {$mod: ["$number", <step>]}]}
```

where `step` is order of magnitude. First, it computes remainder with `$mod` and then it computes difference with `$subtract`.

So, grouping Users by `age` floored to *whole* numbers will be

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {$group: {_id: {$subtract: ["$age", {$mod: ["$age", 1]}] }}} )
```

If you want to floor to 10s or 1000s use 10 or 1000 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB version 3.2 there is a [`$floor`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/) function, so you can simply use:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {$floor: "$age"}}}
])
```