# Get Number of weekdays between two dates in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo DB. Can anyone help me in how to get the number of weekdays between two Given dates.

**$dayOfWeek** of a date will give the value of the date 0 for sunday and 7 for saturday.

But my question is how can i increment the date from start date to end date to find the number of weekdays.

Sample Data:

```
 > db.data.insert({"startDate":ISODate('2016-0101'), "endDate":ISODate('2016-02-02')})  

    WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
    > db.data.find().pretty()
    { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c6e6a6a1e49d654caca17a"), 
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2016-02-02T00:00:00Z")
    }
```

Now need to find the number of Weekdays between the Start Date (2016-01-01) and End Date (2016-02-02).

I can write a function which accepts the start date and end date, but in that function how to iterate from the start date to end date?

Any help is requested.

Comment: Could you add query where it's required?

Comment: @tarashypka : Updated my question

Comment: MongoDB accepts simple Javascript, so any existing solution should work : see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464268/find-day-difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekend-days

Comment: What about the case where start date day is weekday and/or end date day is weekday? Do you want amount of weekdays between 2 dates including those dates?

Comment: @tarashypka Yes I require the count of including those dates selected if its a weekday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find total amount of weekdays between 2 dates you can subtract total amount of weekends from total amount of days. The main problem here is to find total amount of weekends.

**Example** [2016-12-23; 2017-01-01]

> _Dec23___Dec24___Dec25____... ____Dec30___Dec31___Jan01___...
>
> __Fri______Sat_____Sun______...______Fri_____Sat_____Sun_____...

As you see, there are 4 weekends between those dates (Dec24, Dec25, Dec31 and Jan01).

**Solution**

One way to solve it programmatically is to use *aggregation framework* with its *arithmetic* and *date aggregation operators*.

It could be done with splitting the task into 2 subtasks:

1. Find amount of *full weeks* between `startDate` and `endDate` (name it `weeksBetween`). In the above example `weeksBetween = 1`.
2. Find amount of *full days* between `startDate + 7 * weeksBetween` and `endDate` (name it `left`, it could be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6). In the above example `left = 3` (left days are Fri, Sat and Sun). Of interest are amount of weekends in those left days (name it `left_weekends`, it could be 0,1 or 2). In the above example `left_weekends = 2`.

Then, total amount of weekends is `2 * weeksBetween + left_weekends`. In the above example it's `2 * 1 + 2 = 4`.

To find `left_weekends` you can use [**$dayOfWeek**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/) *date aggregation operator*.

1. for Sun `dayOfWeek = 1` and `left_weekends = 1` if `left` is 1,2,3,4,5 or `left_weekends = 2` if `left` is 6 (including Sun and next Sat).
2. for Mon `dayOfWeek = 2` and `left_weekends = 0` if `left` is 1,2,3,4 or `left_weekends = 1` if `left` is 5 or `left_weekends = 2` if `left` is 6 (including next Sat and Sun).

...

7. for Sat `dayOfWeek = 7` and `left_weekends = 2` for any `left`.

Hence, there are next rules we can use:

1. If `remainder > 7`, then `left_weekends = 2`.
2. If `remainder = 7`, then `left_weekends = 1` for Mon-Sat and `left_weekends = 2` for Sun.
3. If `remainder < 7` then `left_weekends = 0` for Mon-Sat and `left_weekends = 1` for Sun.

Here, `remainder = dayOfWeek + left`.

**Query**

```
db.dates.aggregate(
  {
    $project:
      {
        "daysBetween":
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $floor:
                  {
                    $divide: [
                      { $subtract: [ "$endDate", "$startDate" ] },
                      1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    ]
                  }
              },
              1
            ]
          },
        "startDay": { $dayOfWeek: "$startDate" },
        "endDay": { $dayOfWeek: "$endDate" }
      }
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        "daysBetween": "$daysBetween",
        "weeksBetween": { $floor: { $divide: [ "$daysBetween", 7 ] } },
        "startDay": "$startDay",
        "remainder":
          {
            $add: [
              { $abs: { $subtract: [ "$endDay", "$startDay" ] } },
              "$startDay"
            ]
          }
      }
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        "weekendsBetween":
          {
            $add: [
              { $multiply: [ "$weeksBetween", 2 ] },
              {
                $cond:
                  {
                    if: { $gt: [ "$remainder", 7 ] },
                    then: 2,
                    else:
                      {
                        $cond:
                          {
                            if: { $eq: [ "$remainder", 7 ] },
                            then: 1,
                            else: 0
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$startDay", 1 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }
            ]
          },
        "daysBetween": "$daysBetween"
      }
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        "weekdaysBetween": { $subtract: [ "$daysBetween", "$weekendsBetween" ] }
      }
  }
);
```

**Sample**

```
{ "_id": 1, "startDate": ISODate("2016-12-23T00:00:00Z"), 
            "endDate":   ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id": 2, "startDate": ISODate("2016-12-23T00:00:00Z"), 
            "endDate":   ISODate("2017-01-09T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id": 3, "startDate": ISODate("2016-12-23T00:00:00Z"), 
            "endDate":   ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00Z") }
```

**Results**

```
{ "_id": 1, "weekdaysBetween" : 6 }
{ "_id": 2, "weekdaysBetween" : 12 }
{ "_id": 3, "weekdaysBetween" : 19 }
```

**PS** Extending last `$project` stage you can also get total amounts of days and weekends between 2 dates. Don't forget to change collection name before testing the query.

Comment: When I am executing the given code I am getting the following error... And Idea on this???

Error:

assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$sum'",
        "code" : 15999,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed 
: aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:9 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13

Comment: If yours MongoDB version is prior to 3.2, than use `$add` *arithmetic aggregation operator* instead of `$sum`. Updated the answer.

Comment: i tired to do this in the Coding Ground provided by tutorialspoint

Comment: It uses v3.0.9. You can check it with `db.version()` command. `$sum` operator does not work in `$project` stage for v.3.0.9. Replace it with `$add` operator as I said and did in the answer.

Comment: I have replaced the sum with the add and have removed the $floor and $abs as there both also was available only in 3.2. Then i am getting the output like 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d011e6e6d6fa2c2c0998ae"), "weekdaysbetween" : null }  
Even when i gave a start date as month begenning and end date as month end date. Any idea on this?

Comment: `$abs` is not required if `$startDate` is always smaller than `$endDate`, I added it to handle possible irregularities. If you want to leave it, than replace it with [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator (available since v2.6). According to `$floor` operator, you can replace it for older versions as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554156/how-to-aggregate-by-floor-in-mongodb).